# "You wouldn't mind ...do you?" or, "...would you?"

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I'm writing a story, but I seem to have forgotten which of the two is correct.

The sentence I used:
"You wouldn't mind if I borrowed this pen, do you?"

But I want to know if it should be:

> "You wouldn't mind, ***do*** you?"

or:

> "You wouldn't mind, ***would*** you?"

Answer (score 2):

**Tags are helping verbs or modals** and must match the **tense** of the main verb:

- You wouldn't mind if a borrowed this pen, would  you?
- You **like** coffee, **don't  you**?

***Do you*** is only be appended to a verb in the present tense.

- You **speak** Russian, **don't you**?
- You'**d like** to go, **wouldn't you**?
- You **should go** tomorrow, **shouldn't you**?
- **They're speaking** French, **aren't they**?
- **He's** leaving now, **isn't**  he?
- **You've got** it now, **haven't you?** [just to be funny]